# Inverted colors react-native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I don't understand how react-native works...
I use the XCode emulator and my Android Phone.
The colors are inverted. I don't know why. Also, I try to set background-color, but it doesn't help.

IOS:

[image]

Android:

[image]

Comment: Is the Android device running in dark mode and the iOS device running in light mode? Meaning, at the OS level, not an app setting

Comment: It's true.... Thanks